# Grouped Aggregation on multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to perform a few aggregations on a groupby object.  I would like to do this possibly on different columns and possibly with more than one aggregation per column.

#### Example

```
In [1]: from pandas import *

In [2]: df = DataFrame([[1, 'Alice',   100],
                        [2, 'Bob',    -200],
                        [3, 'Alice',   300],
                        [4, 'Dennis',  400],
                        [5, 'Bob',    -500]], 
               columns=['id', 'name', 'amount'])

In [3]: g = df.groupby('name')

In [4]: g.summarize({'num_ids': g.id.nunique(), 
                     'total_amount': g.amount.sum(),
                     'max_amount': g.amount.max()})
```

I understand that this is not valid syntax.  I hope that it is clear what I'm trying to achieve.

What is the best way to accomplish this with Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right out of the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns)

```
gb = g.agg({'id': pd.Series.nunique, 
            'amount': [np.sum, np.max]})
```

Then if you want to to rename columns, just assign to `.columns`.

```
gb.columns = ['num_ids', 'total_amount', 'max_amount']
```

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you could do both the list trick and the dict trick stacked one on top of the other. Thanks @chrisb